# Digit grouping of mysql query result

Tags: mysql, output

I have MYSQL query

```
mysql --batch --disable-column-names -uroot -pXXXXXX --database data -e 'SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table.name' ;
```

what gives me a result

```
6878387
```

Is it possible to have the same output with digit grouping like

```
6 878 387
```

Comment: I suspect that the effort required to achieve that is greater than the reward

Comment: Maybe you're right, but this is why I ask here to understand a possibility for that and what efforts it requires.

Comment: A database is not build for that job, it allows other languages to connect with it and in there you can easily format the number. You're able to do this in MySQL with a couple of `fomat` functions but it will cost performance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Combination of FORMAT and REPLACE would give you desired result

```
select replace(format(count(*),0),',',' ') from table.name
```

Comment: Yes, it works and everything is solved ! Thanks a lot !

Comment: Happy to help! Please consider accepting the answer as well.

Comment: To mark an answer as accepted, please click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.

Comment: Done. Sorry for mistake.